# Taskbar Icon change from code but not changing in deployed ap C# window 10

Tags: c#

i want to change the taskbar icon from code at runtime , all set when run the application but after deploy the app and run from exe file the icon not changing in taskbar , any help .

```
this.icon = resources.green;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Changing the icon of the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246520/c-sharp-changing-the-icon-of-the-taskbar)

Comment: What technology are you using (eg. WinForms, WPF, UWP, etc)? Also, considering `this.icon` is all lowercase, I'm guessing it's a field you created. It's probably not linked to whatever property is actually in control of the taskbar icon for whatever technology you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply changes to mainforms Form.Icon at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899364/apply-changes-to-mainforms-form-icon-at-runtime)

Comment: I am using C# , default icon of form is shown in taskbar , but i want to change the icon ,ie if application is stop then taskbar icon change to red from green , it is working when run from visual studio but not working when run from exe file .

Comment: also it is working in window 7 but not working in window 10